# Как добавить localdb v12?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-localdb

Встал вопрос о работе проги не только на Win8,10, но и на 7.
Чтобы с Win 7 все подружить нужно юзать SQL Server 2014.
Но после его установки, у меня только один localdb v13, а мне нужно v12.
Что нужно сделать?
[image: Проблемс]

Comment: Нажать в верхнем левом углу кнопочку с зеленым плюсиком и создать новое подключение?

Comment: Так оно не локальное будет, насколько я понял. Точнее правильно будет сказать (localdb) не будет.

Comment: Насколько я понял, localdb надо было выбрать при инсталляции sql сервера. Вы такую опцию выставляли?

Comment: Мне кажется она была. По крайней мере при повторной установке LocalDb, спрашивает восстановить или удалить

Comment: Когда кидаю новую базу (12 версии) в проект, пытаюсь ее открыть, говорит что нужно обновить базу.
Не хочет с ней работать. Что делать?

Comment: Пишет несовместимо с текущим SQL Server. Как так то?

Comment: Я Express версию устанавливал.
Может дело в этом?

Answer (score 3):

Нужно создать экземпляр сервера необходимой версии, при этом на компьютере должна быть установлена предыдущая версия библиотек, в вашем случае 12 версия это SQL 2014 LocalDB:

> C:\Windows\system32>sqllocaldb create "v12.0" "12.0" -s

Имя сервера для подключения к этому экземпляру будет:

```
(LocalDb)\v12.0
```

P.S. Кстати SQL 2014 последняя версия которая работает на x86 системах. Так же стоит учесть, что если открыть базу данных на более поздней версии, то потом не удастся подключить ее на более старой версии, так как более новая версия автоматически обновляет формат файла.